# PowerBI - Pivot table drill down functionality

Tags: pivot, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

I'm new to POWERBI, and am using it to combine multiple large files and summarize data for me.

I'm trying to move away from EXCEL since the files can become large when sharing with others.  I want to use **ROW LEVEL SECURITY** and grant access to specific users.

**My main question is, is there a PIVOT TABLE drill down function in POWERBI?**  I'm unable to find this anywhere in the menus and looking at their forums people are unsure, December 2015 they were "working on it," but there have been no updates from that moderator since.

http://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Can-we-create-pivot-tables-and-pivot-charts-akin-to-Excel-in/td-p/10562

Answer (score 0):

The pivot table (matrix) functionality in Power BI is definitely lacking, compared to Excel. There is no drill-down or "Quick Explore" functionality yet.

If a pivot table isn't essential, you can do drill-downs on bar/column charts (which also gives you the ability to cross-filter other charts on the same page). More information here: https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-drill-down-in-a-visualization/.

In terms of whether pivot tables will be enhanced in Power BI, Amanda Cofsky posted an update on this idea last month that suggests this is a top priority for Microsoft (and indeed asks for input on where they should focus their efforts): https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15844186-pivot-tables-and-breakdown-trees

Comment: Thank you for the response.  For my purposes, Pivot Table drill downs are a must to visualize the data, I'm really surprised that this isn't already a part of PowerBI.  

From the link with Amanda Cofsky, it looks like a lot of people want Pivot Table functions also.

Comment: Absolutely. I'd anticipate seeing some big improvements in this area. But, of course, you can't base a product decision on what might come in the future. You have to evaluate based on what's available now.